# JSX Support in Microsoft's Monaco editor

Tags: jsx, monaco-editor

Does [Monaco editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) support JSX syntax highlighting? I couldn't find any reference related to this.

Answer (score 7):

JSX syntax type checking is 100% supported by monaco-editor. Which is not, is syntax highlighting but it can be accomplished by parsing JSX with a worker that uses TypeScript compiler and using `monaco.editor.deltaDecorations()` to add HTML classes to JSX related tokens and adding CSS to colorize them.

For type checking you need to use TypeScript language, configure TypeScript compiler options and provide JSX typings (React's for example).

For both things, here are some instructions I've written: https://github.com/cancerberoSgx/jsx-alone/blob/master/jsx-explorer/HOWTO_JSX_MONACO.md

Here a working demo: https://cancerberosgx.github.io/jsx-alone/jsx-explorer/

Enjoy

Comment: Will this work with react-monaco-editor as well? https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library but as long as it allows you to get the monaco instance it should.

Comment: Hey again, I'm trying to understand your instructions but having trouble on step 3: add JSX definitions as a monaco model. You use jsx_alone_core_d_ts but say if you are using react you can place that with React at the end of that file. I'm not sure what you mean here. Would it be alright if I sent you am email?

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** Nope.

**NL;PR:**

To date (v0.20.0), it does not support JSX highlighting or commenting, it only supports syntax recognition.

**UPDATE**

I have a custom JSX highlighting and commenting in my project, now available as an npm package: [monaco-jsx-highlighter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monaco-jsx-highlighter), so I take Monaco's highlighting:

[image]

And customize it like this:
[image]

You can try it live: https://codesandbox.io/s/monaco-editor-react-6o4u4?file=/src/index.js.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

Some work has been done [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/264), but is not official and only about syntax.

It can be done, though. This [tool](https://alm-tools.github.io/) has it working. In their repo, they add the "coloring" to it.

The whole idea is to provide a [JSX tokenizer](https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/1af2b0aa677fdfe69230d1f53092801d378258dd/src/app/monaco/languages/typescript/tokenization.ts#L16) to Monaco, which can be plugged into it like in their custom tokenizer [example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-custom-languages).

CodeSandbox has a way to do [it](https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/blob/8f689810edeac7d3afe46dc90745a34305649677/packages/app/src/app/components/CodeEditor/Monaco/workers/syntax-highlighter.js). They add a custom syntax worker that sends soon-to-be-decorations to the editor. I do the [same](https://github.com/devuxd/SeeCodeRun/blob/f4e31175abeabc8fc62e2d1b1d560693773a203a/scr-app/src/utils/JSXColoringProvider.js), but I use [jscodeshift](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift) to get the AST (then findJSXElements) and finally create [inline decorations](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-line-and-inline-decorations) on content changes.

Mine looks like this:
[image: Monaco editor with JSX highlights]